# INSERT in single query into 2 tables postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this 3 tables.

```
Employee
PK : id
name

completedBy
FK : employee_id
FK : order_id

Order
PK : id
date
```

I created form for creating order where i fill infos of order (date) and who completed order. In my form there is a table from which I select the employee and get his id. I want to know if there is possible to insert into tables Order and completedBy with one single query.

Is there any difference in effectivity between using two inserts or using the code in answer ?

Comment: You could create an stored procedure that execute both inserts

Comment: I know that it is possible with two inserts. I just want to know if there is a way with one querry so it would be little more effective

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can be done using a data modifying common table expression:

```
with new_order as (
  insert into orders (id, date) values (1, current_date)
  returning id
)
insert into completedby (employee_id, order_id)
values 
( 42 -- employee_id, 
  (select id from new_order)
);
```

The first part inserts into the `orders` table and returns the ID that was inserted. The second part then inserts the row into the `completedby` table using the known employee_id and retrieving the order_id from the previous step.

**Edit**

if the `id` column in the `orders` table is a `serial` column and you want to let the sequence generate the value you can do that as well:

```
with new_order as (
  insert into orders (date) values (current_date)
  returning id
)
insert into completedby (employee_id, order_id)
values 
( 42 -- employee_id, 
  (select id from new_order)
);
```

Comment: this statement  (select id from new_order) will use returned value ?

Comment: @user2938332: yes that's the ID from the first CTE (named `new_order`)

Comment: and is this approach to problem more effective than using two inserts  or there is no difference ?

Comment: @user2938332 why don't you simply run and test it yourself? Obviously in this case it can not be cheaper than two separate `INSERT` statements as it is doing exactly that - and a bit more.

Comment: I am new to databases so i am not sure how to test it. Running it in pgAdmin for postgresql and comparing execution time ?

Comment: A nice example, @a_horse_with_no_name, how would you modify it to include ON CONFLICT (id) UPDATE (upsert) on both tables?

Comment: How can we replicate this query using knexjs query builder

Comment: Works great when subquery returns one row but gives error if return multiple rows. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. When RETURNING clause returns multiple ids, I just have to replace VALUES with SELECT...FROM new_order