# How to insert multiple rows into dependent table together with row into dependable table in the single transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have similar situation:
[INSERT in single query into 2 tables postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29564179/2674303)

```
completedBy
FK : employee_id
FK : order_id

Order
PK : id
date
```

I have single `Order` entity and collection of `completedBy` entities in my Runtime.

I need to insert it using single sql command. Linked question is not suitable for me because I don't know how many `completedBy` entities I have.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: "*because I don't know how many completedBy entities I have*" - then how would you insert them with a regular INSERT?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will know it in the moment of insert but I don't know it when I compile code

Comment: Why do you **have** to do that using a single statement? Can't you do it in a single transaction? Insert the row in the `"Order"` table (horrible name btw because it requires quoting) and then multiple inserts into the other table, e.g. using JDBC batching

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  It is an option but single statement will help to avoid explicit transaction creation

Comment: What's wrong (or complicated) with explicit transactions?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it requires some additional configuration from java application side and highly likely I don't need transactions in other places of my application

Comment: So why doesn't a CTE suit your needs, as per your linked question? There is no need to know how many of anything ahead of time.

Comment: @404 Do you suggest to auto generate sql using string concatenation?

Comment: You don't need any "configuration". `connection.setAutocommit(false); ... do your inserts...; connection.commit();` - as simple as that

Comment: I believe it will be enough for to use   **@Transactional** annotation over the method because I use spring jdbc rather than usual jdbc

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but anyway is there way to achieve it via single query ?